# Castle windsor LifeStyleTransient() not registering (Upgrade from 2.5 to 3.3)

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have upgraded Castle windsor from 2.5 to 3.3

In 2.5 I use to register it in following way,

```
Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly(assembly)
                 .BasedOn<IMenuProvider>()
                 .Configure(component => component
                 .Named(areaName.ToLowerInvariant() + "." +
                        component.ServiceType.Name.ToLowerInvariant())
                        .LifeStyle.Transient))
```

Now in 3.3 I am not able to use LifeStyle.Transient, it says "Only assignment,call, increment........" I made the below change, the code seems to compile fine but it **doesnot register** the classes implemented by IMenuProvider

```
Register(Classes.FromAssembly(assembly)
                .BasedOn<IMenuProvider>()
                .Configure(component => component
                .Named(areaName.ToLowerInvariant() + "." +
                component.Implementation.Name.ToLowerInvariant())
                .LifestyleTransient()))
```

Based on arpan's comment tried this as well,

```
Register(Classes.FromAssembly(assembly)
                .BasedOn<IMenuProvider>()
                .LifestyleTransient()
                .Configure(component => component
                .Named(areaName.ToLowerInvariant() + "." +
                        component.Implementation.Name.ToLowerInvariant())
                                        .LifestyleTransient()))
```

Still the issue is not solved.

EDIT: =====================================

```
public interface IMenuProvieder
{
     //some function
}

public interface IShorcutMenuProvider:IMenuProvider
{
}
```

As show above I am using Classes.FromAssembly to register it based on IMenuProvider and when I try to retrieve it using,

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<IShortcutMenuProvider>();
```

I get nothing. But if I register it using

```
container.Register(Component.For<IShortcutMenuProvider>().ImplementedBy<ShortcutMenuProvider>());
```

I am able to retrieve the registered ShortcutMenuProvider, (I tried to register component for IMenuProvider implemented by IShortcutMenuProvider but while retrieving I got nothing)

I cannot register every single class implemented by the interface like this. 
still trying to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the solution that fixed my problem,

```
.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(assembly)
                 .BasedOn<IMenuProvider>()
                 .WithService.FromInterface(typeof(IMenuProvider))
                 .Configure(component => component
                  .Named(areaName.ToLowerInvariant() + "." +
                   component.Implementation.Name.ToLowerInvariant()).LifestyleTransient()))
```

WithService.FromInterface(typeof(T)) fixed it for me.

Thanks a lot @samy for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the code doesn't register you `IMenuProvider` implementations, it may be because they are not in the assembly you pass to the container. Try checking the assemblies your components live in. Often a quick and correct way to do this is to use `Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication`

```
container.Register(Classes
    .FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
    .BasedOn<IMenuProvider>()
    .LifestyleTransient()
    .Configure(c => c.Named(c.Implementation.Name.ToLowerInvariant())));
```

EDIT: you can check what handlers exist with a code like

```
container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(IMenuProvider));
```

If no handler is returned, then you should try registering one single component explicitly:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMenuProvider>.ImplementedBy<MyMenuProvider>());
```

Don't forget that you can [debug your container](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Debugger-views.ashx) with lots of information, maybe you have a misconfigured component somewhere but this should throw...

Comment: I have checked, assembly I am passing contains IMenuProvider..I also tried using FromAssemblyInThisApplication() but still issue is not solved

Comment: Are the classes public?

Comment: Yes they are public..everything was working fine when I was on castle.windsor 2.5...after I updgraded to 3.3 I am facing this

Comment: @JigarSheth I edited my answer, please try reducing the surface area of the problem by checking whether handlers are registered or if a component is misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add lifestyletransient before configure:

```
container.Register(
    Classes
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn<"YourInterface">()
    .LifestyleTransient()
    .Configure(c => c.Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<"YourClass">))
    .Anywhere
    .LifestyleTransient()
);
```

Comment: I dont think I can do InterceptorReference.ForType<"YourClass"> 
in my case as the assembly which contains this class is not loaded and the assembly information is passed through the parameter of type Assembly.

Comment: I tried to use LifestyleTransient before configure and leaving the part after configure as it is..but it still didnot fix my problem.